# Page not found (404) Request Method: GET Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000

Tags: python, django

**I got the following error whenever I run the project:**

---

Using the URLconf defined in storefront.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
playground/
The empty path didn’t match any of these.

You’re seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

---

Here is my project(storefront) urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('playground/', include('playground.urls')),

]
```

Here is playground urls.py code:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

 #urlConfig
 urlpatterns=[
    path('hello/', views.say_hello)
 ]
```

Here is views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.
def say_hello(request):
    return HTTPResponse('Hello world')
```

Here is my project settings:

```
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'playground'
 ]
```

Comment: What is the exact URL you are trying to access?

Comment: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/playground/hello/` access this url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

project urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('playground.urls')),

]
```

app urls.py:

```
urlpatterns=[
    path('', views.say_hello)
 ]
```

This will work for Empty route.

Answer (score 1):

You got this error because there is no any empty route in your urls.py.

try this, you will get that page:

```
localhost:8000/playground/hello/
```

OR

make it empty.

```
path('', include('playground.urls'))
```

also make empty route in app urls.py file:

```
path('', views.say_hello)
```

And visit to your browser and type:

```
localhost:8000
```

Simply it will display that page.

Hope you understand

Answer (score -1):

run your command in VS's Terminal
python manage.py runserver
then its give a link then you run that. It will execude this program

Comment: You better to give more descriptive answer.